Swapping between 2 objects in a list c#
I’m trying to sort an array of Student objects alphabetically by name and swap two objects in the list. However, after swapping, I’m noticing that the objects sometimes appear to become identical, and I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening.
for(int i = 0; i < this.lastPosition; i++)
        {
            if(this.list[i].GetName().CompareTo(this.list[i+1].GetName()) > 0) {
                Student temp = this.list[i];
                this.list[i] = this.list[i+1];
                this.list[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }

Before the sorting:
Rina 034377281 Parent: Rozz 044377281
Bina 034377281 Parent: Rozz 044377281
Cina 034377281 Parent: Noa 050569126

After the sorting:
Bina 034377281 Parent: Rozz 044377281
Cina 034377281 Parent: Noa 050569126
Cina 034377281 Parent: Noa 050569126

This is the object StudentList:
public class StudentList
{
    public const int MaxStudent = 38;
    private Student[] list;
    private int lastPosition;

And there is Student:
public class Student
{
    private string name;
    private string phoneNum;
    Parent parent;

I would appreciate your help.

Use List.Insert() instead of the indexer (which will overwrite what is in that position, not move things).

If you see any errors, you should add them to your problem instead of just saying but I can't find a way.

Why do have a GetName function instead of using auto-implemented properties? And then test the CompareTo call with the values you know to be in the list. Is it >0 when it should be? (Or better when you expect it to be)

What is the value of lastPosition? You should probably use i < list.Length - 1 instead.

Your code works fine for me, it swaps the two objects exactly as shown. What are you expecting that's not happening? If you're trying to sort, there are Linq extensions for doing that.

Side note: (list[i], list[i + 1]) = (list[i + 1], list[i]); is a shorter syntax to swap items

Thanks for adding test details. I still can't reproduce. Your code gives me B, C, R. Can you create a minimum, runnable example: include the value of lastPosition, the array creation, etc, but cut out everything you don't need: phone number, parent, etc.

Also this won't sort your list unless you do multiple passes.

Your code seems mostly correct, but I think you might encounter an Index out of Bounds error, because you are comparing  (list[i]) with the next element (list[i+1]). This means when i reaches the second-to-last element (i = lastPosition - 1), you’ll be trying to access list[i+1], which is out of bounds.

We don't know what lastPosition is set to, but if it's the index of the last element in the array (which sounds sensible) there is no out of bounds exception.

Just seen the comment that this was the issue. Clearly the code you posted in the question @MayaTwik is not the code you are running: it's catching the exception and doing the swapping in a different order.

If you want to sort your list of students, simply write
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.GetName()).ToArray();

